# Pumping lemma on a regular language with different variables

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

I have this language
$L = \{a^i b^j c^k ∣ i,j,k \geq 0 \text{ and } i+j=k \}$

I dont know how to replace $i,j,k $ with the pumping length p, usually when I make a string s with the pumping length p I just replace the powers with p. But here I belive I have to do something else. Any tips?

Comment: Try pumping $a^p b^p c^{2p}$ where $p$ is the pumping length

Comment: @Zanzag oh That makes sense, since if i=p , j=p then k=p+p. WIll try to prove it now Thank you mate

Comment: @Zanzag This is what I came to: for p = 2 we get the string: aabbcccc. I choose x=a , y=a and z=bbcccc. Now pumping y we will see that this will violate the language since aaabbcccc is not in the language?

Comment: You don’t choose the pumping length nor the $x, y, z$ substrings in the pumping lemma. I recommend you to read the wiki page on the pumping lemma carefully and understand exactly what it says:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages